# Porting cURL to Android with NDK

Tags: android, curl, android-ndk, cross-compiling

Good day to you. I'm currently struggling at porting cURL onto my Android app - many subjects do talk about this, but no single post or tutorial or whatever does clearly say what to do or just don't work at all.

I do own every single tool needed, have the latest version of cURL (7.28.0). I tried to do it using cross-compiling and a toolchain (part that work good) but when I'm trying to configure the curl-7.28.0, the `./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi` (or any argument that is pass) return the following error :

```
./configure: line 20: $'\r' : unknown command
./configure: line 35: Syntax error near unexpected token « newline »
'/configure: line 35: `     ;;
```

If someone had already gone through this and does have the memories of the steps he followed or knows what I do wrong, it would be a blessing if you could help my poor soul !
Thanks in advance.

*Note : I'm using Cygwin.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Cygwin, I suspect that you have tonj convert all the newlines to the windows format for it to work:

It seems that `configure` has only `\r`, or so called "carriage returns", as new line character. This is actually the notation used by OSX. Most *nixes use just a single newline character to work (`\n`). Only windows needs both: a "carriage return" and a newline character: e.g. `\r\n`.

You can use any professional text editor to change this, for example [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: Alright that fixed that problem, thanks a lot. I'm still far from achieving my initial goal, will keep posted !

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a newline issue in whatever file `configure` is reading. On Windows, lines in text files are terminated with CR/LF (\r\n) - many Unixy tools choke on that.

Visual Studio, among other tools, can recode line termination. Open a file, File\Advanced Save Options, choose Unix line format, then save.

On *nix there's a tool called `dos2unix` that does the same.

Comment: Thing is that the file is 2000+ lines long, so I have not idea what file could have this problem. Plus within the configuration file an extra-care to this possible issue is taken - it's doesn't have any file I've modified, everything is part of a downloaded package.